# x-axis misalignment for subplots with groupby plots and stacked bar plots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, axis

[This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liB3b.jpg)[This is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdMhg.jpg)

My subplots on the right are just stacked bar charts but on the left the data has been grouped and this sorting seems to affect the bins on the x-axis. I can set a shared x axis - this 'looks right' but is incorrect with data plotted in the wrong years on the left. Any solutions?

I have tried sharing and not sharing the x-axis and other changes to x-ticks and x-axis parameters but cannot fix this - except by doctoring the image!

Comment: Please create a [reprex].